Append string after \centering during org-mode table export to latex
I would like to append a string like \smallafter the \centeringcommand when exporting a table from org-mode to latex. Is it possible to do that without modifying the export command? Ideally I would like to use an option like the following
#+CAPTION: Caption
#+LABEL: tab:example
#+ATTR_LATEX: :some_option \small
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
|----------+----------+----------|
| A        | B        | C        |
| D        | E        | F        |

Expected output
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{\label{tab:org3772302}Caption}
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\
\hline
A & B & C\\
D & E & F\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Using a block works for longtable but not for a regular table.That is, the size of the font is the intended when the pdf is produced
#+begin_small
#+CAPTION: Caption
#+LABEL: tab:example
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
|----------+----------+----------|
| A        | B        | C        |
| D        | E        | F        |
#+end_small

Thank you

You can use the :font attribute for that:
#+CAPTION: Caption
#+LABEL: tab:example
#+ATTR_LATEX: :font \small
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
|----------+----------+----------|
| A        | B        | C        |
| D        | E        | F        |

See Tables in LaTeX Export in the manual.

Thanks, I did check the manual but somehow I did not try that
